# Whitelist Redirect URL iOS in Ionic Capacitor

Tags: ios, swift, cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor

I am using the latest version of Ionic and Capacitor app, with Inapp Browser plugin from cordova we are able to login using android devices where the schemes and redirect back to app work fine. But when it comes to ios it just doesn't work. I have added the follwing to Info.list .

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>BiddingHub</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>$(MARKETING_VERSION)</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string>com.bidding.starter</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>com.bidding.starter://oauth?</string>
                <string>com.bidding.starter</string>
                <string>com.bidding.starter://oauth</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION)</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>com.bidding.starter</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIWebView</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The SSO page is loaded in app browser and I enter the credentials I get the auth code but the app redirect is not happening and I get the followig error message in Xcode console

> 2023-07-10 15:21:22.689526+0530 App[15533:197315]
> webView:didFailProvisionalNavigation - 0: Redirection to URL with a
> scheme that is not HTTP(S)

The URL for redirect is

> com.bidding.starter://oauth?state=42jETMms&session_state=780a-80de-e88b88178289&code=x-xxxxxx-xx--x-x-x-x-x-x-x--x-x-x-x-x-

But I have already whitelisted the com.bidding.starter in Info.list, what I am doing wrong, or what am I missing. Lack of Ionic/Capcitor documentation is frustrating.

Comment: Your URL has a scheme of `com.bidding.starter://`. The error tells you that redirection can only happen to URLs that have a scheme of `http://` or `https://`.  This doesn't look to be a bug with ionic, it look like WebKit that is denying the redirection.  It seems likely that you need a `WKNavigationDelegate` for your view.

Comment: Thanks Scott it would be great if you could dumb it down more to me, once the login happens I want my in app browser to be closed and redirect back to Ionic app. So the scheme above is used for app redirection. In android this works, I am not sure how to achieve this in iOS with Ionic. Reg WKNavigationDelegate is there a setting/config  of sorts which does that in Xcode.

Comment: Ionic is building a web view for your app, probably a `WKWebView`. Those views let the app approve or deny any navigation request.  The object that makes policy is a `WKNavigationDelegate`. When the current delegate sees navigation to a URL with a scheme other than "http" or "https" it is blocking it and logging an error.  You should replace that delegate with one to allow your custom scheme. Try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70083637/how-to-access-and-set-wkwebview-configuration-from-appdelegate-in-ios) to get the web view and see if you can change the nav delegate.